# How can I get a client id

Tags: soundcloud

I would like to develop using Sound Cloud API or SDK.
However, it is currently not possible to create a new app in'Sign up for a new app'.
We would appreciate it if you can tell us how to create an app or get a client ID.

Comment: looks like SoundCloud is bombing support messages to Stack Overflow.  Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log into your soundcloud account and go to your browser console, look for a GET request to the API-V2? It should have a client ID there.

Here's a screenshot.

[Soundcloud Clien ID in Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQOq6.png)